# how to communicate to a servlet program from your test classe (using testing / Junit)

Tags: java

I want to send my request to servlet program from my test classes( using TESTING tool). how to achieve this.

Comment: may i know what is your servlet's url-pattern ? also make clear on both Servlet+Testing-program runs on same machine or diff?

Comment: @ Mr. Vishal J Gejera ...... url prattern of my servlet program is "http://localhost:3030/rfc/security". and both my Servlet+Testing-program runs on same machine.